# How to force an NTP time sync at app startup for Android 4.2.1

Tags: android, ntp

In Android 4.2.1, how can I force an NTP time synchronization at my app's startup?

Also, is there a way to configure how often the device will sync it's time and/or which ntp server it will use?

Comment: "sync" is not an event, it is an ongoing process.  You can usu ntpdate to hard set the clock, but since it does not factor out the TX/RX delay it might not be the best option depending on the accuracy of your local clock, how good the drift file is, and how long it was "off" (does the clock have a battery?  Also, NTP determines its own poll rate [normally -- see: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/39194].